# Intercept back button on stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I know it is possible to override headerLeft to which is passed an onPress prop, but how can I intercept when the default back button is pressed (only in certain screens) without the needing to define a new component to assign to headerLeft?

Answer (score 0):

try using `backhandler` provided by react native

learn more on [react native web](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler)

Comment: This way I'm not intercepting the press on the back button on the header...

Comment: So you are using header from the navigation? what navigation are you using? if you are using react navigation then you can read it here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/779